# React router: execute custom function on every <Link> navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Sorry if this has been already answered.
But is there a way to execute a custom function on every `<Link>` navigation? Preferably without creating a custom `<Link>` wrapper.

I'd like to put some information to sessionStorage before every navigation inside my application.

Thanks

Comment: Only `Link` navigation or every history change?

Answer (score 25):

You can use `onClick` to perform any action, say

```
<Link
  to="/"
  onClick={() => console.log('Heading to /')} />
```

Replace `console.log` with a function that would perform `sessionStorage` update and such, and that's it.

---

Another way would be to use `onEnter` prop of `Route` component to execute a certain function per every route enter:

```
<Route
  path="/"
  component={App}
  onEnter={() => console.log('Entered /')} />
```

See the [reference](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#onenternextstate-replace-callback), or [example with react-router and react-redux](https://github.com/taxigy/til/blob/master/redux/react-router-action-on-enter.md).

Comment: I would like to not write the `onClick={() => console.log('Heading to /')}` part every time I use `<Link>`

Comment: You didn't specify this constraint in your original question. Why won't you?

Comment: Yes, you're right. My bad, I should have specified this in my original answer. The reason I dont want to do this is because I'm using `<Link>` on like 30 different places and adjusting it would be kinda hard.

Comment: Isn't as hard as to create a custom component for that, just think about times a few months in future you forget what custom `Link` component is for. :) I think there's another way, just updated the answer.

Comment: onEnter of Route is now deprecated in react-router v4

Comment: Hey Anurag, thanks for bringing this up! What’s the new way then? (if any)

Comment: @rishat from v5 you'd use useLocation() hook and check pathname and do stuff based on that.

Answer (score 15):

I was literally looking for this answer and couldn't find it anywhere and then I did some experimenting and this was my answer that helped me, so I thought I'd share!

If you use the **uselocation** hook by React Router. This hook gives you an object with a **key** property that changes on every router change. You can then create a useEffect that watches for this property and fire a function when that **key** changes. See example below

```
const location = useLocation();
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('location', location.key); // { key: "3uu089" }
    // Fire whatever function you need.
    sessionStorage.setItem('whatever', state);

}, [location.key]);
```

Comment: I used `location.pathname` rather than what you suggested. My `useEffect` gets fired on every change of url

Answer (score 0):

You can call any function on the route object of react router like the below:

```
function someFunction(a,b){ 
 const c = a + b;
 return c
} 


<Switch>
  <Route exact exact path="/" component={SomeComponent} />
  <Route path="/reload" render= {(props)=>someFunction() } />
</Switch>
```