# Reset Search State in Redux If User Leaves Page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm using Redux to store the state of a search value. Here's my Search component and my reducer

Search Component

```
const Search = props => {
  const handleSearch = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    props.searchChange(event.target.value.toLowerCase());
  };

  const handleFilter = event => {
    props.filterChange(event.target.value);
  };

  const style = {
    marginBottom: 10
  };

  return (
    <div style={style}>
      search
      <input onChange={handleSearch} />
      <select onChange={handleFilter}>
        <option value="DESC">Sort Likes Descending</option>
        <option value="ASC">Sort Likes Ascending</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    search: state.search,
    filter: state.filter
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { searchChange, filterChange })(Search);
```

and my action creator and reducer

```
    export const searchChange = search => {
      return {
        type: "SET_SEARCH",
        search
      };
    };

    const searchReducer = (state = null, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case "SET_SEARCH":
          return action.search;
        default:
          return state;
      }
    };
```

If i search for something it correctly filters out the identified items.  If I click to another page however, and come back, the state of the search value remains.  Thus, a user has to refresh the page for the search value to be cleared.  And in some cases i'm finding that the state doesn't clear when the page is refreshed.  Where and how should i be resetting the 'search' state?

Here is my Blogs component (note i am also calling the Search component here) which is where I am displaying a list of blog items;

```
const searchBlogs = ({ blogs, search }) => {
  return search
    ? blogs.filter(a => a.title.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()))
    : blogs;
};

const Blogs = ({ blogsToShow, filter }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Search />
      <div>
        <h3>Blogs</h3>
        <Table striped celled>
          <Table.Header>
            <Table.Row>
              <Table.HeaderCell>Blog Title</Table.HeaderCell>
            </Table.Row>
          </Table.Header>
          <Table.Body>
            {filter === "DESC"
              ? blogsToShow
                  .sort((a, b) => b.likes - a.likes)
                  .map(blog => (
                    <Table.Row key={blog.id}>
                      <Table.Cell>
                        <Link to={`/blogs/${blog.id}`}>{blog.title}</Link>
                      </Table.Cell>
                    </Table.Row>
                  ))
              : blogsToShow
                  .sort((a, b) => a.likes - b.likes)
                  .map(blog => (
                    <Table.Row key={blog.id}>
                      <Table.Cell>
                        <Link to={`/blogs/${blog.id}`}>{blog.title}</Link>
                      </Table.Cell>
                    </Table.Row>
                  ))}
          </Table.Body>
        </Table>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    blogs: state.blogs,
    filter: state.filter,
    blogsToShow: searchBlogs(state)
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Blogs);
```

Comment: You need a `CLEAR_SEARCH` action creator, return a `null` when it is dispatched in your reducer.  Then you need to fire off this action on navigate.  What is `Link`?  Can you fire off the action there?

Comment: hmm, okay that makes sense.  Link is just the React Router linking component which is providing link to a new page...so can't do it there.

Comment: Yes, you can fire off a dispatch in a `Link` call: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39294424/react-router-execute-custom-function-on-every-link-navigation

Comment: well, well, well, thank you, amazing that you can do that....i have a solution i'll post down below, it's ugly, but it's working, and I guess that's all that matters...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

thanks to Kyle's help I did the following:

created a new action creator and reducer as follows:

```
export const clearSearch = search => {
  return {
    type: "RESET_SEARCH",
    search
  };
};


const searchReducer = (state = null, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_SEARCH":
      return action.search;
    case "RESET_SEARCH":
      return null;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

For any link that a user can click i just included a call to the clearSearch action creator.  The main issue with this is that not only did i have to do it on my  for the individual blog post, but for any other page link on the site.  It was a quick fix, but if any links are added, they would need to include the clear fix, making it a bit messy.

```
import { clearSearch } from "../reducers/searchReducer";

 const clear = () => {
    clearSearch();
  };

<Link onClick={() => clear()} style={padding} to="/blogs">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a new action like

```
export const searchChange = search => {
  return {
    type: "RESET_SEARCH"
  };
};
```

And in your reducer you could just set to INITIAL_STATE:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    ... 
    search: ''
    ... 
}

const searchReducer = (state = null, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case "RESET_SEARCH":
          return INITIAL_STATE;
        default:
          return state;
      }
    };
```